# POST Request from one website to another in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-development-server

I need to make a POST request from an application running on SERVER1 to an application running on SERVER2.

**SERVER1:**

```html
<form name="submitForm" method="POST" action="http://SERVER2:4120/download_item/">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_field" value="G78328">
    <a href="javascript:document.submitForm.submit()">Click on the link</a>
</form>
```

**SERVER2:**

```js
router.post('/download_item', async function(req, res) {
   itemid= req.body.item_field;
});
```

This method works when I run both the applications on the same server (localhost) but doesn't work on different servers.

Comment: Can you ping from `SERVER1` to `SERVER2`?

Comment: Yes, I could ping from SERVER1 to SERVER2.

Answer (score 0):

you can run your multiple server at same time in npm. For both servers two instance need to be created then only you can access between two servers.

Comment: Yes, in case of two server instances on the same hardware, it works. By servers I meant two different physical hardware.